# Will Earth become a gas giant when the Sun expands in 5 billion years?

Tags: the-sun, earth

Because if the Sun expands to 1 AU or very close to it, its density and hold on outer layers will be much weaker so a dense object like the Earth can slowly absorb material because Earth would be much denser than the outermost regions and would the Earth become a gas giant from it?Would there be some iron in the outermost regions of the expanded sun which when falling onto Earth make the inner core bigger?

Comment: The Sun will not become a red giant for more than 7 billion years.

Answer (score 11):

The opposite. The Earth orbits at 30 km/s. The Sun's material would not have comparable net rotation, so the Earth would be subjected to a 30 km/s wind. This wind would easily strip off the Earth's atmosphere, and it would continue to strip any of the Sun's gas that got temporarily captured by the Earth.

Even without the wind, the temperature would likely be far too high for any gas to remain bound to the Earth, because the thermal velocities would exceed the Earth's escape velocity.

Comment: Would a solar expansion to 1AU put enough resistance on earth that it would start to slow down and spiral into the sun?

Comment: Wouldn't the Earth's magnetic field cause the solar wind to strike the Earth directly causing Northern Lights instead of strip away the Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: @RussellHankins It depends on how much wind there is. Particles trapped in a magnetic field exert their own magnetic field in the opposite direction. With enough charged particles, the Earth's magnetic field would be completely counteracted.

Comment: @Questor Indeed, the earth would slow down gradually and, given enough time, sink into the sun. Not my field but, last I heard, this is the expected outcome.